Memory leak in async grpc streaming server
I'm having a memory leak problem in my async streaming gRPC code:
class MyAsyncGrpcStreamingServer {
public:

    void init(grpc::ServerBuilder& builder) {
        builder.RegisterService(&myserviceService);
        completionQueue_ = builder.AddCompletionQueue();
        grpcServer_ = builder.BuildAndStart();

        grpc::HealthCheckServiceInterface* hcService = grpcServer_->GetHealthCheckService();
        hcService->SetServingStatus("test.mycompany.myservice", true);
        hcService->SetServingStatus(true); // Applies if service name is not specified in request

        // Start the HandleRpcs function in a separate thread
        rpc_handler_thread_ = std::thread(&MyAsyncGrpcStreamingServer::HandleRpcs, this);
    }

    std::unique_ptr<grpc::Server> grpcServer_;
    std::atomic<bool> shutdown;
    std::unique_ptr<grpc::ServerCompletionQueue> completionQueue_;
    std::thread rpc_handler_thread_;
    MyService::AsyncService myserviceService;

    class CallDataBase {
    protected:
        CallStatus status_ = CREATE;
        grpc::ServerContext serverContext_; // one per request handler created
    public:
        virtual void Proceed() = 0;
        virtual void Stop() = 0;
        virtual ~CallDataBase() {}
    };

    class CallDataStream final : public CallDataBase {
    protected:
        myserviceServiceStreamRequest request_;
        myserviceServiceStreamResponse reply_;
        grpc::ServerAsyncWriter<decltype(reply_)> streaming_responder;
        bool first_time_process = true;
        grpc::Alarm alarm;
        myserviceService::AsyncService *myserviceService_;
        grpc::ServerCompletionQueue* cq_; 

    public:
        CallDataStreammyservice(myserviceService::AsyncService* myserviceService, grpc::ServerCompletionQueue* cq) :
            streaming_responder_(&serverContext_), myserviceService_(myserviceService), cq_(cq){
            Proceed();
        }

        void Proceed() override {                
            if (status_ == CREATE) {
                status_ = PROCESS;
                myserviceService_.RequestStreammyservice(&serverContext_, &request_, &streaming_responder_,
                    cq_, cq_, this);
            } else if (status_ == PROCESS) {

                if (first_time_process) {                
                    new CallDataStreammyservice(myserviceService_, cq_);                
                    first_time_process = false;
                }

                if (shutdown) {
                    status_ = FINISH;
                    streaming_responder_.Finish(::grpc::Status::OK, this);
                } else {

                        // Pretend there's no data to be written yet, requeue the event

                        printf("WAITING FOR DATA...\n");

                        alarm_.Set(myserviceService_->completionQueue_.get(), gpr_now(gpr_clock_type::GPR_CLOCK_REALTIME), this);                    
                }

            } else {
                // Finish
                delete this;
            }
        }

        void Stop() override {
            status_ = FINISH;
        }
    };


    void HandleRpcs() {
        new CallDataStreammyservice(&myserviceService, completionQueue_.get());
        void* tag;
        bool ok;
        while (!shutdown) {
            bool ret = completionQueue_->Next(&tag, &ok);
            if(!ret) { // Queue has been shut down
                break;
            }
            if (!ok) { // Request didn't succeed
                static_cast<CallDataBase*>(tag)->Stop();
                continue;
            }
            static_cast<CallDataBase*>(tag)->Proceed();
        }
    }
};

This code simulates a "data not ready" (I stripped this down from the production code) continuously and it's called by python like this
self.__myservice_channel = grpc.aio.insecure_channel(f"{request._myservice_urls[0]}")
self.__myservice_service = myserviceService(self.__myservice_channel)
self.__myservice_stream = await self.__myservice_service.stream_myservice()

Even just creating the stream like above and letting the gRPC runtime loop, continuously grows host memory while the program does nothing and runs
WAITING FOR DATA...
WAITING FOR DATA...
WAITING FOR DATA...
WAITING FOR DATA...

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong in the code above to trigger the memory leak, also because as far as I understand alarms can be reused now
